# JPA mapping of two tables using and when to use jointable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

This is more of a general 'understanding' question rather than a specific senario question.

I have been lookiing at the ways in which JPA maps tables together and found two examples here that seem to work in different ways.

One has a Set of Phone objects using @JoinTable to join STUDENT_PHONE to STUDENT by STUDENT_ID

The other has a Set of StockDailyRecord but seems to just use mappedby stock and in the stock_detail table object have the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation.

Simply trying to get an understanding of which method would be the prefered way and why?

Method 1:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_PHONE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID") })
public Set<Phone> getStudentPhoneNumbers() {
    return this.studentPhoneNumbers;
}
```

Method 2:

```
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "mkyongdb", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock")
public Set<StockDailyRecord> getStockDailyRecords() {
    return this.stockDailyRecords;
}


@Table(name = "stock_detail", catalog = "mkyongdb")

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Stock getStock() {
    return this.stock;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method #2:**

It uses an extra column to build the OneToMany relation. This column is a Foreign key column of the other table. Before building the relation **if these data needs to be added** to the database then this foreign key column needs to be defined as **nullable**. This breaks the efficiency and cannot provide a normalized schema.

**Method #1:**

It uses a third table and is the efficient way to store data in a relational database and provides a normalized schema. So where possible its better to use this approach, if the data needs to be existed before building the relation.

Comment: Thanks for this. So Method #1 is more STUDENT -> STUDENT_PHONE <- PHONE? Whereas Method #2 is STOCK-> STOCK_DETAIL (fk stock_id)? Is method #1 not more of a ManyToMany join then?

Comment: Yes. Both Method #1 & #2 can be used for ManyToOne and OneToMany. But method #1 is the only option for ManyToMany.